# Ensure each element in an array of objects contains a unique value for a key

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo collection like so:

```
{
  _id: 'asdasdasd',
  battletag: 'battletag#1290',
  games: [{
    id: "somegameid",
    name: "Starcraft II",
    characters: ['corvid'],
    groups: ['Husky Starcraft']
  }, {
    id: "someothergameid",
    name: "World of Warcraft",
    characters: ['corvid', 'crow', 'crowtoe'],
    groups: ['Warlords of Draenor']
  }]
}
```

I want to ensure that, for every game in `games`, the id attribute is unique. Is there a way to ensure uniqueness on values in arrays of objects in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on mongoDB built-in `_id`. Create another collection with all the games, and refer to it using its documents `_id` in the Games array of your collection. You can still store all data not directly related to the game in the Games array, along with the game `_id`

Comment: True, but more of my concern is trying to insert the same `game._id` twice. That is, you try to update the array to contain Starcraft II twice.

Comment: You should just move each `games` items elements in a dedicated collection. Each entry will have its own `_id` and you can store them in a simple string array `Games`. You might need to include the original document `_id` in your new collection items as well.

Comment: I thought the idea with mongodb was to _de_normalize and that's a more SQL-like approach?

Comment: We need someone more experienced than me to answer that. I just advised what seemed to make sense to me, but it could be an SQL-like approach (and moreover not efficient). If someone has an approach fitting better into mongoDB philosophy, I would like to see it. I am definitely not skilled enough to answer meta questions.